# create C++ object only in heap

Tags: c++, class, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { printf("constructor"); };
private:
    ~A() {};

};
int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    void *p = new A(); //ok
    void *p = new A[5]; //error
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create object only in heap (that is to say only through `new`),so I set the default destructor to `private`. However,it works when I use `new A()` to create only one object,it doesn't work when I use `new A[5]`. Why? I am confused. Thanks so much!

Comment: By creating only on heap you mean to always have memory leak?

Comment: You can define a factory function to allocate an array. Just make that factory function a `friend` of the class. @R Sahu has already [explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434407/464581) the direct approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The steps involved in executing `new A[5]` are:

1. Allocate the required amount of memory.
2. Initialize each object by using the default constructor.
3. Return a pointer to the allocated memory.

If an exception is thrown in the second step above, the implementation is required to:

1. Call the destructor on all objects that have been initialized.
2. Deallocate memory.
3. Deal with the exception.

Because of this, the `new []` implementation needs to be able to access the destructor of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Try this workaround. It allocates on the heap not only the objects, but also the array:

**[EDIT]** Thanks to the advice of @M.M I can write a better way to do this: **NOT** use generic pointers and declare the appropriate pointer's types for each allocation, then the code will be a lot more simplified:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A
{
public:
    A() { printf("constructor"); };
private:
    ~A() {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A *p1 = new A(); // ok. not using generic pointer
    A **p2 = new A*[5]; // no error anymore, also there's not a generic pointer involved
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        p2[i] = new A();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense and the code causes undefined behaviour, all you have done is suppress warning/error messages

Comment: Edited. Why is causing undefined behavior? It works fine for me.

Comment: `void **` can only point to an object of type `void *`, however the object being pointed at is actually of type `A *`. So it is a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: Of course, you are right. But it works when you make the appropriate casting when acceding an element. I know it's a hard work, but the question already uses generic `void` pointers. I believe that the use of generic pointers is dangerous, and must be avoided when possible. But the question uses it, I only tried to **not** modify the code so much. However, tell me if I'm right and the appropriate casting can manage this to edit my answer with this information.

Comment: Well your answer does not use the appropriate casting ... you would have to write `((A **)p2)[i] = new A();` and so on.  Which seems absolutely worse than just writing `A** p2` in the first place. The original code is poor to use `void *` instead of `A *`, it's not a mistake worth copying

Comment: Thanks, it's done. Look! It's so clear now... it shines.

Comment: Good job. I would suggest just having the second program, it seems to me there is no need to retain the `void *` version